# Weird behavior of javascript date api for the year 1941/1942

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server

I noticed an odd interpretation of timestamps by the javascript Date api.
For all the Dates included between **01/10/1941** and **31/03/1942**, the interpretation subtract 1 to the actual hour, leading to display errors when the stored time is 0h00.

I store thoses dates in a SQLServer db; then they are retrieved in a Java entity through Hibernate, and eventually they are served to the client browser as a webservice.

In the following 2 exemples, you can see that according to whether the date is between **01/10/1941** and **31/03/1942** or not, the result displayed by javascript Date constructor is not the same...

I know this period was quite a mess in France (where the browser is running) : the 2nd world war and France occupation by a foreign administration made the standards quite erratic...  but I am quite sceptic about the fact that this is the cause of my problem : that would imply that the javascript Date api applies very specific rules... and that java does not apply the same!

Indeed, I may be wrong... but I still have a problem anyway : though there are not that many users born during that period, I still need to display their birthday correctly. 
So, any tip, explanation, suggestion are welcomed here!

```
------------- SQLSERVER --------------
User.birthday : DATETIME 
=> update user set birthday = cast('31/10/1941' as date) where id = xxx 
=> select User.birthday where id = xxx 
=> 1941-10-31 00:00:00.000
------------- JAVA --------------
User.java => User.birthDay : java.util.Date
=> Hibernate => User u = selectById(xxx);
=> u.getBirthDay().cdate : 1941-10-31T00:00:00.000+0200
=> u.getBirthDay().getTime() : -888976800000
=> u.getBirthDay().getClass() : java.sql.Timestamp
------------ JAVASCRIPT ------------------
new Date(-888976800000) => Thu Oct 30 1941 23:00:00 GMT+0100




------------- SQLSERVER --------------
User.birthday : DATETIME 
=> update user set birthday = cast('26/09/1941' as date) where id = xxx 
=> select User.birthday where id = xxx 
=> 1941-09-26 00:00:00.000
------------- JAVA --------------
User.java => User.BirthDay : java.util.Date
=> Hibernate => User u = selectById(xxx);
=> u.getBirthDay().cdate : 1941-09-26T00:00:00.000+0200
=> u.getBirthDay().getTime() : -892000800000
=> u.getBirthDay().getClass() : java.sql.Timestamp
------------ JAVASCRIPT ------------------
new Date(-892000800000) => Fri Sep 26 1941 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

Thanks for reading until here.

Comment: `new Date("1941-09-26T00:00:00.000+0200")` can be used in Chrome at least

Comment: It seems entirely plausible to me that Java and your browser are using different time zone implementations/data.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about France time zones is most probably correct.
If you print GMT/UTC time, it outputs correctly:

```
new Date(-888976800000).toUTCString(); // "Thu, 30 Oct 1941 22:00:00 GMT"
new Date(-892000800000).toUTCString(); // "Thu, 25 Sep 1941 22:00:00 GMT"
```

My advice would be to use UTC dates for everything, and only as a last step apply timezone correction.

Ask yourself: if John was born on `Feb 12th` in Japan, and it's `Feb 12th` in Japan, but only `Feb 11th` in France, does he already have a birthday or not?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand and absolutely agree with the UTC-related rule, though It's a bit too late on the project to apply it everywhere. Now I am trying to see whether I should "cheat", and add +1h (in base) to all related birthdays, or do something with the sql and/or column/field to avoid such border effects....

Comment: You can try `new Date(-888976800000).getTimezoneOffset()` — it should give you different results for different timestamps based on the timezone at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with dates for Italy (Italy kept daylight saving during both winters of 1940/1941 and 1941/1942).

Since all major browser (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) showed the same behavior, I suspected that they were working as intended. In fact, checking the JavaScript specs I noted that until [version 5.1 of the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.8) it was stated that

```
The implementation of ECMAScript should not try to determine whether the 
exact time was subject to daylight saving time, but just whether daylight 
saving time would have been in effect if the current daylight saving time 
algorithm had been used at the time. This avoids complications such as 
taking into account the years that the locale observed daylight saving 
time year round.
```

From this i *think* that it means that it will simply apply the timezone rules currently in use even if at the time they were not valid. This would explain your issue.

In [version 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-daylight-saving-time-adjustment) the same thing has been worded differently:

```
An implementation dependent algorithm using best available information on 
time zones to determine the local daylight saving time adjustment 
DaylightSavingTA(t), measured in milliseconds. An implementation of 
ECMAScript is expected to make its best effort to determine the local 
daylight saving time adjustment.

NOTE It is recommended that implementations use the time zone information 
     of the IANA Time Zone Database http://www.iana.org/time-zones/.
```

This means that in theory we can expect an ES6 compliant browser to return the correct answer, but since it is still a "best effort", this is not guaranteed (and in fact no one of the browser I tried did it correctly).

If you already use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to handle date/time in javascript, you may want to use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), since it has its own timezone database and will return the right answer (minus converting from ms to seconds and vice-versa).

```
> new Date(-888976800000)
Thu Oct 30 1941 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) [wrong answer]
> moment("1941-10-31 00:00:00").unix()
-888973200 [wrong answer]
> moment.tz("1941-10-31 00:00:00", "Europe/Paris").unix()
-888976800 [right answer]
```

Comment: Marco, your analysis is very intersting. I do not use moment.js at the moment, but I may consider using it as soon as I go back developing client-side. Thanks for your very usefull feedback!